# Disable Button Style within Datepicker in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I've defined a Style for all buttons in App.xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    </Style>
```

While designing my view I used a Datepicker that is influenced by this Style. The included button for opening the calender is not aligned correctly. Therefore I tried to disable this Button Style for the Datepicker using Style="{x:Null}" but I don't know, where I can find the place to add this code.

Is there any way to do this without setting a key for the style in App.xaml?

Thanks

Comment: could you please add you date picker control's xamal

Answer (score 0):

Your first style without x:Key is responsible to apply all controls of the defined type if there haven't any custom style.

You can solve this in two ways:

- Add Style="{x:Null}" as you mentioned.
- Add another style with x:Key and add this customized style to avoid the default.

#### Edit 1:

Of course, search the original style of an Datepicker in WPF and modify the button style on it.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:DatePicker">
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
<Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="#FF444444" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:DatePicker">
            <Grid x:Name="Root">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <!-- Main DatePicker Brushes -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#8CFFFFFF" />

                    <!-- Button Template -->
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                        <vsm:VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        <vsm:VisualTransition To="Pressed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF448DCA" />
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <!--Start UI-->
                            <Grid Height="18" Width="19" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Background="#11FFFFFF">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="23*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Margin="-1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" x:Name="Highlight" />
                                <Border x:Name="Background" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="1" CornerRadius=".5" Background="#FF1F3B53" />
                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#BF000000" Opacity="1" CornerRadius=".5">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF494949" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" Stretch="Fill" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Width="3" Height="3" />
                                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" x:Name="DisabledVisual" />
                            </Grid>
                            <!--End UI-->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                    </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                    </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <controlsPrimitives:DatePickerTextBox x:Name="TextBox" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TextBox}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <system:Boolean>true</system:Boolean>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ToolTip.Triggers>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <Grid Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                        <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" />
                        <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#FFFFFF" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>                        
                <Button x:Name="Button" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
                <Grid x:Name="DisabledVisual" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="#8CFFFFFF" />
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="#8CFFFFFF" Grid.Column="1" Height="18" Width="19" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
                </Grid>
                <Popup x:Name="Popup" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And the button in question localized in the Datepicker is this:

```
<Button x:Name="Button" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
```

Just change/add the sytle as `{x:Null}` or an `{StaticResource CustomStyleIdefined}`

#### Edit 2:

Adding the url of Datepicker style
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc278067(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned you repeated only what I just said. I don't know where I can set Style="{x:Null}" within the Datepicker, can you show me an example please?

Comment: Hi @user6695058 I just updated my answer. Think about that another solution is adding a custom style for it.